# Possible cross point function bug

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, teechart

I'm evaluating TChartProVCL for XE3.

I created 2 manual series:

1) Series1, a stair-step line
2) Series2, a simple line intersecting Series1 at various points

I then created a calculated series, X Cross Points, which should be the cross points of Series1 and Series2.

It looks fine, except at x=6, and x=5.6 (approx.)  **This looks like a bug to me.**

[image]

My ultimate goal, FYI, is to color the regions inside the series.  A TRegionBandTool would get close, but I need to color the areas above and below Series1 with different colors.

Comment: You can send your files at http://www.steema.net/upload/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: user, upload your image to your favorite image sharing service and post the link here, I'll add it to your question.

Comment: I thought YOU were my favorite image sharing service :-) ... Okay - try this: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151283377343950&set=a.104488678949.90537.829828949&type=1&theater

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the TCrossPointsFunction doesn't support sources set with the Stairs mode.
I've added it to the wish list to be implemented in future releases.

Comment: Thanks for having a look.  I've seen threads in which you once had a similar problem with the TSeriesBandTool when used with a stair-step series, which is now fixed (TV52013891).  It looks that at the same time, someone requested the very solution I'm looking for, (TV52013892).  Where can I find the status of these issues?

Comment: TV52013891 is fixed (TSeriesBandTool with Stairs). TV52013892 isn't closed yet, but it's a bit different from the discussed here; it asks for the possbility to have two different gradients in the TSeriesBandTool. TCrossPointsFunction has no relation with TSeriesBandTool. And I'm afraid Steema's tickets aren't publicly available.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me be clear about what I'm trying to do.  Again, I'd like do the same exact thing using TSeriesBandTool with two colors as requested here by JosefG in 2010: 
http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10873
Because this is still not possible, I was looking at perhaps using TCrossPointsFunction to create the different regions myself.  This is NOT my ideal solution to start with, and since it doesn't work correctly with stair step lines, it's not a solution at all.
We have purchased the source so I can implement my own solution. Please consider bumping up the priority. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In the case of using the "stair-step" series with the TCrossPointsFunction I've discovered a simple "cheat" that is good enough for my purposes.  I merely:

1. Turn OFF the stair-step property.
2. Create the stair step effect by placing two points very close together on the X axis.

For example:

```
const
    UPPER = 85;
    LOWER = 75;
begin
    SysThresh.Clear;
    for i := 0 to 8 do
        SysThresh.AddXY(i, UPPER);
    SysThresh.AddXY(8.001, LOWER);
    SysThresh.AddXY(12.999, LOWER);
    for i := 13 to 25 do
        SysThresh.AddXY(i, UPPER);
```

This gives me the stair step effect without confusing the TCrossPointsFunction.